# Bigquery SQL to convert single value string to multi value based on separator/prefix

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column value string with + or - orefix as below :

```
id       val
 1    +a+b+c-d-e-f+g
```

Now based on + or - separator I need to build the dataset as follows :

```
 id new_val prefix
 1   a       +
 1   b       +
 1   c       +
 1   d       -
 1   e       -
 1   f       -
 1   g       +
```

And to add the string is not fixed length ie it would continue with either separator (+ or -) for different rows.
Any guide on big-query SQL to do this transformation would be helpful.

Update :

I am using this query but missing some value though  :

```
with mytable as (
  select 1 as id, '+a+b+c-d-f+g' as val1, 
)

select * from (
select id, new_val1 , '+' symbol
from mytable, unnest(split(val1,  '+')) as new_val1 WITH OFFSET AS val1_offset
union all
select id, new_val1 , '-' symbol
from mytable, unnest(split(val1,  '-')) as new_val1 WITH OFFSET AS val1_offset
) where length(new_val1) = 1 and new_val1 is not null
```

Comment: I am using this query but missing some value though :

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select id, substr(part, 2) new_val, substr(part, 1, 1) prefix
from `project.dataset.table`, 
unnest(regexp_extract_all(val, r'[+-][^+-]+')) part
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The split into substrings can be done, by adding a further separator, which does the string do not contains:

```
select id, substr(vals,2) as new_val, substr(vals,1,1) as prefix
from (
SELECT id, split(substr(replace(replace(val,'-',';-'),'+',';+'),2) ,';') as val_tmp

from (select 1 as id,  "+a+b+c-d-e-f+g" as val)

) as t, unnest(t.val_tmp) as vals
```

If you have more than `+` and `-`, regex would be a better option:

```
SELECT id, split(substr(REGEXP_REPLACE(val,r"([+-]+)", ";\\1"),2) ,';') as val_tmp
```